# Magento 2.1.5 In product detail page Price remove after decimal

Tags: magento2.1.5

In Magneto2.1.5 product detail page remove decimal after price display like this $20.00 instead of $20 but this is not fix it please if any solution reply my post I have share my site screen[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution in this issue please go to your theme-Magento_catalog/product/price/final_price.phtml and replace below code

```
echo str_replace('.00', '',$block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [

            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'skip_adjustments'  => true
        ]));
```

Here i have use str_replace function u can use all price add this function and you have one js file path go to price-utils.js  and line no 84 replace this

> return pattern.replace('%s', r).replace(/^\s\s*/,
>   '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '').replace('.00','');

Thanks, hope it will be helps.